# Woocommerce smart coupons disable Store credit receiver "Send to different people"

Tags: woocommerce

Is there anyway i can remove or disable Store credit receiver "Send to different people" and keep the send to one person only?

screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN7Mx.png

Answer (score 0):

in style.css do this:

```
.gift-certificate sc_info_box{display:none}
```